# What is the best way to manipulate an API AJAX JSON response and pass it to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I think I have a tough one for you guys. Or at least it's been tough for me. I've been searching for the best way to do this in Stack Overflow and everyone that has asked has been given a different response.

I have this code that is accessing an API and calling a maintenance list of all the vehicles in a fleet.

```
function getMaintenanceList() {
  var settings = {
    "url": "API URL HERE",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer token here"
  },
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    // The response the API sends is a JSON object.
// It is an array.

var jsonMaintenance = response;
    var parsedJson = JSON.stringify(jsonMaintenance);

//Left over code from when I was trying to
//pass the data directly into the other page
// I was unable to do so
//return jsonMaintenance;

//Left over code from when this was in a PHP file
//and I was posting the stringified response to the page
// for testing purpose
//I had to disable CORS in Google Chrome to test the response out
//console.log(jsonMaintenance);
//document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = parsedJson;

});

};
```

The code above works well. What I was attempting to do here was write the stringified response to a file. Save that file in the server. Call it from another page using JavaScript and save it as an object in JavaScript, parse it using JSON.parse(), and then pull the required information.

Here's an explanation as to why I'm trying to do it this way. When I call the maintenance list from the API, I'm getting the entire maintenance list from the API, but I need to be able to display only parts of the information from the list.

On one page, we'll call it vehicle-list.php, on it I have a list of all the vehicles in our fleet. They all have unit numbers assigned to them. When I click on a unit number on this page it'll take me to another page which has more information on the vehicle such as the VIN number, license plate, etc. we'll call this page vehicle-info.php. We're using this page for all the vehicles' information, in other words, when we click on different unit numbers on vehicle-list.php it'll always take us to vehicle-info.php. We're only updating the DOM when we go to the page.

I only want to include the information specific to each vehicle unit in the page along with the other info in the DOM. And I only want to call the info from the API once as I am limited to a certain amount of calls for that API. This is why I am attempting to do it this way.

I will say that what I originally wanted to do was get this JSON response once every 24 hours by using a function in vehicle-list.php save the reponse as a variable as seen above `var jsonMaintenance = response;` and then just access certain parts of the array every time a unit number is clicked. However, I have been unable to access the variable in any other page. I've written many test files attempting to call `jsonMaintenance` without success so I've been trying to to just save it as a text file to the server and I haven't been able to figure that out either.

After explaining all of the above. My questions are these:

How do I best manipulate this data to accomplish what I want to accomplish? What would be the best standard? Is the above code even the right way to call the data for what I'm trying to do?

There doesn't seem to be a set standard on accomplishing any of this when I search on Stack Overflow. I'd like to be as efficient as possible.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you just want to make one Sever call and share the information across multiple pages, and you don't want the information to be remembered by the Browser use a `$_SESSION`. Otherwise I would just use JavaScript `localStorage`. I would use PHP for `json_encode()`ed data and have JavaScript ready to accept AJAX information to update the DOM.

Comment: Is it possible for you to link an example? I've never heard or seen what you're talking about and I'm very interested in learning more. Having a new lead is exciting.

Comment: There isn't a set standard because there are multiple ways to do it depending on your needs. For instance some information is too sensitive to keep client side, regardless of the fact that most users would never notice it or know its importance. If it's trivial data then I'd suggest pulling from the database and caching it in localStorage.

Comment: `session_start(); if(isset($_POST['getData']){ /* query to $queryObj */ $_SESSION['maint'] = $queryObj; } if(isset($_SESSION['maint'])){ echo json_encode($_SESSION['maint']); }` There's way more to it.

Comment: **IF the data isn't sensitive**, then as @StackSlave has mentioned, look into [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). Hth

Comment: The data is sensitive as it has the vehicles' license plates and VIN numbers.

Comment: What if I want to store the data in the server?

Answer (score 2):

there is a lot of ways how you pass your data through your website after getting it in from an api call, the best approach is to store these information in a database and call it back in which ever way you want, you can do that as far as you are using php, you can store it to sql or to access, if you don't want to store these information in a database like in sql or access, then best way is to store it to localStorage and call it back whenever you want.
I will show you briefly how you can do that, if you want better explanation post an example of your returned data.

to store an item in localstorage use,

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

to call an item back from localstorage use,

```
var somevar = localStorage.getItem('key')
```

to remove specific item from localstorage use,

```
localStorage.removeItem('key')
```

to clear all items saved to localstorage use,

```
localStorage.clear()
```

be aware storing the data to localStorage is only at the station you are using

Comment: By 'station' do you mean a single computer or server. If so, that's okay because I want to store it on my server where we're hosting our web pages. We're trying to avoid putting this information in a database. The site with the API from where we're pulling the information from is serving as a sort of database where we have a lot of information. We're pulling this info in order to display it and share it. Is it possible for you to link an example of how this is accomplished? Thank you for your time. I appreciate the lead.

Comment: it will be stored on the server localStorage if you are opening the site page on the server, I would want to help you and write a good code but I still didn't figure out exactly how you want to handle the returned information, its only about giving you the right directions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it somehow like this.

1. Call the maintenance list from the API with the **server side** language of your choice which seems to be `PHP` in your case. Lets say the script is called: `get-list.php`. This can be triggered by a cron job running `get-list.php` in intervals limited to the certain amount of calls that you are allowed to do for that API. Or if you are not able to create cron jobs then trigger the same `get-list.php` with an `AJAX`-call (eg `jQuery.get('sld.tld/get-list.php')` - in this case `get-list.php` have to figure out if its the right time to call the API or not).
2. Now that you have the data you can prepare it as you want and store it as a `JSON`-string in a text file or database of your choice. If I get you right you have a specific dataset for each vehicle, which have to be identified by an id (you named it "unit number") so your `JSON` would look kind of: `{"unit1": { property1: "val1", property2: "val2" }, "unit2": { property1: "valXYZ", property2: "valABC" }}` or alike.
3. Now when you link to `vehicle-info.php` from `vehicle-list.php`, you do it like so: `<a href="sld.tld/vehicle-info.php?id=unit1">ancor</a>` or similar as well. Of course you can also grab the data with `AJAX`, its just important to deliver `vehicle-info.php` the corresponding unit number (or id - better to say) and you are good to go.
4. `vehicle-info.php` now have all there is to render the page, which is the complete data set stored in text file or data base and the id (unit number) to know which part of the whole dataset to extract.

I wanted to give you this different approach because in my experience this should work out just so much better. If you are working server side (eg `PHP`) you have write permissions which is not the case for `JavaScript`-client side. And also performance is not so much of an issue. For instance its not an issue if you have heavy manipulating on the data set at the `get-list.php`-level. It can run for minutes and once its done it stores the ready-to-use-data making it staticly available without any further impact on performance.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If i ran into a similiar problem i would just store the data in a database of my own and call it from there, considering you are only (willing/abe/allowed) to request the data from the API very rarely but need to operate on the data quite frequently (whenever someone clicks on a specific vehice on your applicaiton) this seems like the best course of action.

So rather than querying the data on client side, I'd call it from server, store it on server and and have the client operate on that data.

Comment: We're actually trying to avoid that, but we may have to go that route. We're trying to  move most our information onto the site that is providing the API for efficiency reasons. It also serves a sort of database so the more information we move to the better.

Comment: I have no clue why this is getting downvoted meanwhile solutions that suggest, storing potentially enourmous amounts of data (very little of which is actually gonna be used) on client side are trending to be accepted answers.

Comment: The list is actually quite small and we'll be using all of it. We'll be using all the data from our API calls.

Comment: There is a difference of needing it all and getting it WHEN you need it, you are also opening yourself up to inconstiencies (different clients could show different data depending on when they got and stored the information from the api in the local storage), if you have access to the api you are getting (you talked about moving your information there) you should just provide an endpoint that allows you to query only the data you need.

Comment: We just need to show the information for work purposes. People need to see the data. No need to get frustrated with me , sir. I did not downvote your answer, I am unable to as I am a new user. We need to call the information and have it on the server like you said and then show it to people who need it on our own work site. The site that has all our vehicle info is specialized for other purposes and does not readily show the information. It is inefficient. Also, we have other information besides the maintenance list that we need on the work site. We need all this information together.

Comment: We are trying to eliminate going to multiple different sites to get all our necessary info. This is to improve efficiency. If you wanted to know why, you could have just asked. I'm not 'arguing' with you.

Comment: Just because you would be storing the information in a database on your server it wouldn't mean that users would have to go to another site. The information is now available on the server and you have all the power in the world  to control where the information is displayed on your site.

Comment: Like you mentioned earlier that when you click on a certain vehicle it makes a request that coressponds to the vehicle-info.php, once you have the information stored in your database you could just edit vehicle-info.php to return the additionial data that is now stored in your database in addition to the information that you were serving before.